# Mongodb returning object inside array element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this mongoose schema,

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const productSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  image: { type: String, required: true },
  saleSizes: [      //Sizes that a particular item has, ex.. Size P , M, G XG
    {
      saleSize: { type: String, required: true }, //actual sizes, ex.. P
      price: { type: Number, required: true }, // sales price for size P 
    },
  ],
  category: { type: String, required: true },
  active: { type: Boolean, default: true },
});

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
module.exports = Product;
```

when I load the page , I use the find() method to list all my itens with the sale sizes and prices.
this is the function that i'm using.

```
function homeController() {
  return {
    async index(req, res) {
      const products = await Product.find();
      
      console.log(products);

      const categories = [
        ...new Set(products.map((product) => product.category)),
      ];
      return res.render('home', { products: products, categories: categories });
    },
  };
}
```

the return for the find() method is this.

```
[
  {
    active: true,
    _id: 60affa70d981bc59b64f2e09,
    name: 'Alface Americana',
    image: 'alface-americana.png',
    saleSizes: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    category: 'Hortaliças'
  },
  {
    active: true,
    _id: 60affa70d981bc59b64f2e0a,
    name: 'Couve',
    image: 'Couve.png',
    saleSizes: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    category: 'Hortaliças'
  },
  {
    active: true,
    _id: 60affa70d981bc59b64f2e0b,
    name: 'Agrião',
    image: 'agriao.png',
    saleSizes: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    category: 'Hortaliças'
  },
  {
    active: true,
    _id: 60affa70d981bc59b64f2e0c,
    name: 'Rúcula',
    image: 'rucula.png',
    saleSizes: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    category: 'Hortaliças'
  },
  {
    active: true,
    _id: 60affa70d981bc59b64f2e0d,
    name: 'Limão Taiti',
    image: 'limao-taiti.png',
    saleSizes: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    category: 'Frutas'
  },
  {
    active: true,
    _id: 60affa70d981bc59b64f2e0e,
    name: 'Goiaba Vermelha',
    image: 'goiaba-vermelha.png',
    saleSizes: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    category: 'Frutas'
  }

....
]
```

Note that saleSizes Properties return as array of objects.

```
saleSizes: [ [Object], [Object] ].
```

I need the return to be something like this.

```
{
    active: true,
    _id: 60affa70d981bc59b64f2e18,
    name: 'Granola',
    image: 'granola.png',
    price: '500',
    saleSizes: [
                {saleSize: "P", price: "100"}, 
                {saleSize: "G", price: "200"} 
               ],
    category: 'Grãos'
  }
```

what is the best approach to accomplish that?.

PS: sorry for my English, i'm from Brasil and still Learning (I think this is a forever process).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is returned correctly. `saleSizes` is the array of Objects. `{saleSize: "P", price: "100"}` is Object. You can try to access those nested objects like this:

```
let size = saleSizes[0].saleSize;
let price = saleSizes[0].price;
```

Answer (score 0):

After Nenad Milosavljevic comment, I change my html code to this.

```
<% product.saleSizes.forEach(function (saleSize){%>
        <span class="font-bold text-lg">R$ <%= saleSize.price %></span>
        <button
          type="button"
          class="size py-1 px-4 rounded-full uppercase text-xs"
        ><%= saleSize.saleSize %>
        </button>

<% })%>
```

I'm using EJS by the way, now I have a button for each sale Size and a price as well.

Thank You so much for the Help, I was trying to solve a problem that isn't a problem.